# Backup jailbreak

Tags: jailbreak

I had a jailbreak on my iPod 5 (6.1.2) but then I upgraded it to 6.1.3 and I had backed it up when it was jailbroken and when i had restored it it asked if I wanted to use a backup and I used the one I did while I was jailbroken and now I have battery percentage on my iPod 5. How can I make sure it's jailbroken or not. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Battery percentage is a normal feature. Based on what you described, you are not jailbroken. But the way to verify it is see if you have the Cydia app installed.

Comment: Battery percentage is not normal on an iPod touch. It's set in a .plist, though, so if you restore from a backup that had it, you'll still have battery percentage.